# Athena MSCK repair table returns 'tables not in metastore'

Tags: amazon-athena

While running MSCK repair tablename command, `athena` query editor returns an error `tables not in metastore`.
But table exists and I can query on that table.

I have data kept in `S3` in form of `parquet files`, `partitioned` with
`hash` as partition key (partitions look like `hash=0`, `hash=100` and so on), and I am running glue `crawler` to create a table in `Athena`.

I know `partitions not in metastore` is common issues and there are solutions to fix it. But I am not able to find the solution for `tables not in metastore`

Has anyone solved similar issue, or have an idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Does the IAM role being used to execute the query have permission to read that S3 bucket? I had this error when running a query from Lambda using a role which did not have `ListBucket` permission on the bucket in question.

Comment: yes @chris. It has s3 bucket policy but I figured out it to be issue with Glue policy. minimum required glue permissions are `"glue:BatchCreatePartition",
 "glue:CreatePartition",
 "glue:DeletePartition",
 "glue:BatchDeletePartition",
 "glue:UpdatePartition",
 "glue:GetPartition",
 "glue:GetPartitions",
 "glue:BatchGetPartition" `

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by selecting the correct database from dropdown menu on the left of query editor.  I had run the previous setup query on sampledb and then i was trying to run a new query but the new tab changed the db to default.  Changing default to sampledb fixed the issue!